# How to make Uri image smaller?

Tags: java, android, image-processing, image-resizing

I'm new to java and I'm struggeling to work out how I can resize an image before uploading it to firebase.

I have read and tried many suggestions from stack but I haven't got anything to work.

I only need the image to be a few 100 kilobytes. The image will only be used for a profilepicture beside the name (40dp*40dp). So the quality dosen't need to be that good. So I'm not looking for any fancy compression, just a simple way to reduce the image. Like redcuing the width and height to only be lets say 80dp*(aspect ratio).

I'm getting the image from a users phone like this:

```
private void openFileChooser() {

    Intent intent = new Intent();

    intent.setType("image/*");
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    startActivityForResult(intent, PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST);

}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
     super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

     if (requestCode == PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null && data.getData() != null) {

         imageURI = data.getData();

        Picasso.with(this).load(imageURI).fit().centerCrop().into(imgView);

    }
}
```

And uploading it to the database:

```
 private void uploadFile() {

    if (imageURI != null && getUserId != null) {

        final StorageReference ref = mStorage.child(getUserId);


        UploadTask uploadTask = ref.putFile(imageURI);
 }
```

I tried an extension like this, but it didn't help

```
 private void uploadFile() {

    if (imageURI != null && getUserId != null) {

        final StorageReference ref = mStorage.child(getUserId);

        Uri test = new Compressor() {
            public Uri compressToFile(Uri imageURI) {
                return imageURI;
            }

            @Override
            public String getMessageEncoding() {
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            public OutputStream compress(OutputStream os) throws IOException {
                return null;
            }
        }.compressToFile(imageURI);


        UploadTask uploadTask = ref.putFile(test);
}
```

All answers that I found didn't have the image as an Uri so I'm a bit confused. I will probably need the image as an Uri for firebase. Can anyone show me a step by step guid on how to do this. Appreciate all help!

Answer (score 1):

You can Use an Imagecompressor Library For this purpose
https://github.com/zetbaitsu/Compressor

Comment: I tried this but I didn't get it to work. See code above. Do you know what I do wrong?